# Confused about togglesoftinput function

Tags: android

I know that the function is used to toggle the soft input, as per the documentation. But I am confused about how the flags work that are passed as parameters. Any example would be appreciable (I want the explanation too so that I get the exact functioning). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Showing Softkeyboard -

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(imm != null){
        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
```

Hiding SoftKeyboard -

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(imm != null){
        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful of how the flags work. And how the function is toggling the state. thanks!

Comment: @gauravjain if u find it useful, then up-vote and accept the answer... :)